# windows phone 7 how to navigate to settings menu

Tags: windows-phone-7, settings, location

I have a windows phone 7 app that uses GPS to track user position. Now the user can disable this feature through the phone's setting menu.  the app handles this disabling fine and gives them a message. This is all pretty standard windows phone stuff.

My question is whether I can navigate (inside the app) to the settings menu so that the user can enable phone location services? Ideally I would give them a link or a button that they touch and they are then taken out of the app to the settings menu.  They would then click 'back' and return to the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, at the moment, there's no way to fire up the `Settings` menu from inside your app.

Comment: There seems to be an app named toggle in the marketplace that is doing it.

Comment: This answer was posted before Mango was released. Toggle is using an API introduced in Mango called the `ConnectionSettingsTask`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394011%28VS.92%29.aspx. It does not launch the `Settings` menu, but preset sections within the settings menu.

Comment: Toggle doesnt take you to the location services screen as there is no task for that, even in Mango.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(“ms-settings-location:”));
```

Not sure if it works on WP7 though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx